# generating function as english statement

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

An ordinary enumerator is given as $(1+x+x^2)^p$.  This is being understood as follows:

> There are 2 each of p kinds of objects.The ordinary enumerator for
>   selecting none (or) one (or) both the objects of that kind is
>   $(1+x+x^2)^p$

Similarly,how do i visualize (or) understand the enumerator 
**$(1+x^5+x^9)^{100}$** 
in plain english

Comment: It seems to me the example "plain English" statement relies on the term *ordinary enumerator* without giving a definition.  At best the statement is a kind of illustrative example, but it doesn't seem all that clear (perhaps leading to your difficulty in applying it to a quite similar example).  Should we back up and give an understandable account of *generating functions*?

Comment: @hardmath The actual question was to find coeffecient of (x^23) in (1+x^5+x^9)^100.An explanation leading to it's answer would be really great.

Comment: We could adapt the methods of computation I used in [this recent Answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1326586/3111) to find that coefficient.  The wording of the Question above suggests you want an *interpretation* of (all) coefficients, which probably has a large number of valid responses, while the algebra of the polynomial, though somewhat tedious, has a well-defined result.

Comment: @hardmath In the link mentioned above, how did we convert $(1 + x^2 + x^4 + ... + x^{18} + x^{20})^2$ to 
$(\frac{1 - x^{21}}{1 - x})^2$. Is there a formula ?

Comment: This is just the usual formula for a geometric sum.  It doesn't apply in any obvious way to your problem.

Comment: @hardmath Oh sorry.stupid question to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relating that polynomial to your own example, we can understand $(1+x^5+x^9)^{100}$ as follows:

> There are $9$ each of $100$ kinds of objects. The ordinary enumerator for selecting none or five or all nine of the objects of that kind is $(1+x^5+x^9)^{100}$.

Here's another interpretation:

> Consider three-sided dice whose faces have $0$, $5$, or $9$ pips, and roll $100$ such dice. Then the coefficient of $x^k$ in $(1+x^5+x^9)^{100}$ is the number of ways to get a total of $k$.

Comment: The second example was great.Thanks..!!

Comment: @Pradeep I find the second example a lot easier to understand too!